# How to Custom each List item view with image from drawable?

Tags: android, imageview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-lists

For example if i have to create custom list view about type of food, in each list_item consist of food type logo, food type name. If i store food type name in string resource and store picture of each food type in drawable.

1) How can i get the picture from drawable and set to List view? 
2) How to get the picture that match name of food type

Thanks you in advance.

```
public class FoodListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private CustomListAdapter listAdapter;
    private String[] food_type_name;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.foodlistholder);

       food_type_name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.food_name_array);


        listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_food, food_type_name);



        setListAdapter(listAdapter);


    private class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        private String[] items;

        public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if(v == null){
                LayoutInflater  vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_food, null);
            }

            TextView foodNameStr = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.food_name_txt);

            foodNameStr.setText(items[position]);
                //How to set Image view form drawable, which match the food's type name

        return v;


    }

  }

}
```

Comment: better go through this example http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: thanks you for your anser, however, i thought there would be some more pretty solution. Following that link, it has only 2 image(R.drawable.no and R.drawable.ok) it use if/ese condition to switch 2 image. What if, i have a lot of type of food may be 40 list item. Do i need to write a condition to switch it all 40 items? if it so i will do a switch case. anyway, thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you did by setting the text, but for a ImageView.

```
ImageView foodPhoto = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.food_photo);
foodPhoto.setImageDrawable(foodDrawable);
```

You just need to create a list of drawable ids to know which drawable to use.